# Как делать dump-ы БД средствами C# в MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

В старых версиях Visual Studio была библиотека "MySQLDump", но сейчас её убрали.

Есть ли какая-нибудь актуальная замена?

Про вариант с батником я знаю.

Comment: `Про вариант с батником я знаю.` Ну а чем он плох?

Comment: Я про него плохого не говорил. Считаю его достойным вариантом.

Мне просто интересно есть ли альтернативы.

Comment: Вот [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311492/backing-up-database-in-mysql-using-c-sharp), но я сейчас с телефона, и не готов написать перевод для полноценного ответа.

Comment: Попробовал MySqlBackup - пишет что нет класса. Какой из ответов того вопроса рабочий?

Comment: @SigmaProgrammer конечно его нет, это же сторонняя библиотека, которую сперва надо установить `(:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом.

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C " 
путь_до_mysqldump.exe -uПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ -hХОСТ -pПАРОЛЬ название_БД > путь_к_файлу_дампа.sql
);
```

Comment: А зачем вызывать через cmd, разве никак напрямую, через целевой exe-файл?

Comment: У меня получилось передать параметры только в таком виде.